# Tenho django no python anywhere minha view que gera pdf funciona localmente mas no servidor da erro!

Tags: python, django, pdf

Olá, tenho um sistema em django/python bem simples pra gerenciar sorteios, e ultilizo o xhtml2pdf pra gerar relatorios em pdf, quando ultilizo ele localmente ele funciona perfeitamente fiz o deploy no python anywhere todo o sistema funciona normal menos  a view que gera o pdf com os dados!!
uso o django 3.1
coloquei essa pergunta no stack a alguns minutos e foi rejeitada por falta de detalhes, eu sou iniciante, perguntas detalhadas requer um nivel mais profissional. se me ajudar eu tento mostrar o meu problema!

[image: ESSE É O ERRO QUE RECEBO NO TEMPLATE]

ESSE É O CODIGO DA VIEW

```
def render_pdf_view(request):
hoje = date.today()
dias = ('Segunda-feira', 'Terça-feira', 'Quarta-feira', 'Quinta-feira', 'Sexta-feira', 'Sábado', 'Domingo')
hj = dias[hoje.weekday()]
hora_agora = datetime.now()
hora = hora_agora.strftime('%H:%M')
acertivos = Escolha.objects.filter(sorteado=True).count()
pessoa = Pessoa.objects.all()

template_path = 'pdf_template/invoice.html'
context = {
    'hj':hj,
    'hora':hora,
    'hoje':hoje,
    'pessoa': pessoa,
    'acertivos':acertivos,
}
# Create a Django response object, and specify content_type as pdf
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}.pdf"'.format(hoje)
# find the template and render it.
template = get_template(template_path)
html = template.render(context)

# create a pdf
pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(
   html, dest=response )
# if error then show some funy view
if pisa_status.err:
   return HttpResponse('We had some errors <pre>' + html + '</pre>')
return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro não é erro de código , possivelmente as portas que estas a usar no servidor estão a bloquear por algum motivo. Tenta correr numa porta diferente:

Acrescenta ao **settings.py**:

```js
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

e depois fazes **python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9191** [ou outra porta qualquer]

Comment: Se me permite, como posso fazer isso direto no servidor?

Comment: em que portas estas a correr o serviço? e que servidor estas a usar?

Comment: Eu so criei a aplicação que basicamente, gerenciar numeros de sorteio, nada de especial, porem quero gerar relatorios em pdf, entao tenho esta view que ai que pega os dados do model(nome, id, acertos e etc) e joga tudo num pdf, porem a porta que eu uso localmente é a padrao do django :8000 entao somente subi ele pra o python anywhere.

Comment: já atualizei a resposta, tenta fazer isto

Comment: devo rodar o python manage.... no bash do python anywhere? desculpe se to sendo ignorante mas a porta nao é setada automaticamente assim que eu faço o deploy? Esse esquema de gerar pdf funciona perfeitamente no ambiente local!

Comment: sim eu sei que funciona todo localmente , mas por vezes quando se tenta implementar as coisas não correm como nos esperamos. O teu erro não é devido ao código , mas sim onde está implementado. Ao tentar mudar as portas onde esta a correr o teu programa , pode vir a resolver o assunto , contudo uma outra solução [link] (https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/3485/) como está descrito neste fórum , o python anywhere , usa uma proxy para filtrar registos ,( para utilizadores não pagantes), e pode estar a ser bloqueado ai

Comment: show cara, Vou seguir o que o link que me mandou pede pra fazer! muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda!! quaso dê certo posto aqui!!

Comment: Caso dê certo basta fazer upvote ao meu comentário para pessoas com o mesmo problema verem a solução